# how to add members to the group while creating user in camunda platform

Tags: wildfly-10, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm new to camunda platform.can you guys give a hint to do this.
While creating a new user in camunda,i have created a text field to mention the group name that the user wants to join.my query is How can i add this user under the group members list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a `PUT` request on `/group/{groupId}/members/{userId}`
to add an member to a group. The `groupId` should identify the group and 
the `userId` the user which should be added.

See for more information the [documentation](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/group/members/put/).